# Listing Tales in HTML5 using API and Javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have an sql database with one table called "Tale", which has 2 rows: "ID", "Tale" containing 10 tales. I would like to list them to an HTML page. If I run the html, the result is "Undefined" ten times. Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Mesék</title>
    <link href="mesekStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <p id="cim">Mesék</p>

    <form>
        <div id='meselist'>

        </div>
        <div>
            <input id='meseText' type='text' placeholder='Ide írd a mesét' />
        </div>
        <button id='addButton' type='button' >Új mese felvétele</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('addButton').addEventListener('click', () => {

            let data = {
                meseText: document.getElementById('meseText').value
            }

            fetch('api/tales',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                }
            ).then(x => {
                if (x.ok) {
                    alert('Siker');

                } else {
                    alert('Kudarc');
                }
            });
        });

        function MeseBetöltés() {
            fetch('api/tales')
                .then(result => {
                    if (!result.ok) {
                        console.error(`Hibás letöltés: ${result.status}`);
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return result.json();
                    }
                })
                .then(data => {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        document.getElementById("meselist").innerHTML += data[i].meseText += "<br/>"
                    }
                })
        }
        window.onload = () => {
            MeseBetöltés();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I tried adding new tales trough the textbox "meseText" and saving it with the button "addButton", and it works, it adds a new column to the SQL table but with the value NULL. Can you please help?
Here is the API Controller:

```
using HajosTeszt.MeseModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace HajosTeszt.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/tales")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MeseController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<MeseController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Tale> Get()
        {
            MeseContext context = new MeseContext();
            return context.Tales.ToList();
        }

        // GET api/<MeseController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Tale Get(int id)
        {
            MeseContext context = new MeseContext();
            var keresettMese = (from x in context.Tales
                                where x.Id == id
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();
            return keresettMese;
        }

        // POST api/<MeseController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Tale újMese)
        {
            MeseContext context = new MeseContext();
            context.Tales.Add(újMese);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // PUT api/<MeseController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<MeseController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            MeseContext context = new MeseContext();
            var törlendőMese = (from x in context.Tales
                                where x.Id == id
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();
            context.Remove(törlendőMese);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("count")]
        public int M1()
        {
            MeseContext context = new MeseContext();
            int mesékszáma = context.Tales.Count();
            return mesékszáma;
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems like you're a lot confused about what is front-end and what is back-end. The question is: what format your `api/tales` endpoint returns?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in fetching the data

```
fetch(`{your backend base url}/api/tales`)
```

Explanation -> If you use `/api/tales` then the browser will interpret it as `{your frontend base url}/api/tales` therefore you need to specify the base URL, ie, `{your backend base url}/api/tales`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is my backend url? I'm sorry for the stupid question, I'm haven't really dealed with backend yet.

Comment: You need to make a server that will fetch and serve the data in the required format. You can use Django, fast API, express, etc.